# Cordova Android disable bubble animation at top of page

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I have recently upgraded my cordova android application to use crosswalk. Prior to upgrading, if I pulled down at the top of a page on my phone, nothing would happen, which is what is expected. But under crosswalk I get the android stretching bubble at the top of the screen to notify that I've reached the top.

Several parts of my application have pull to refresh functionality and the android animation takes away from the feel. Is there anyway to disable this in Cordova + Crosswalk?